# Строковой калькулятор

Tags: java, android

Понимаю, как сделать обычный калькулятор с кнопками + - * /. Но имею трудности, чтобы сделать строковой, где есть одно поле и кнопка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не прошу дать готовый код. Прошу пояснить или дать подсказку как подойти к этому решению. Правильно ли будет: разбить математическое выражение на куски/части и каждый заносить в переменную, а потом сложить ? Или существует другой подход ? Буду благодарен за какой-нибудь внешний ресурс, чтобы почитать.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button buttonCalc;
    TextView result;
    EditText task;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        buttonCalc =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalc);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
}
```

Comment: [тык](https://google.gik-team.com/?q=%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80), [ОПЗ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Существует огромное количество подходов для решения данной задачи. Классика состоит в следующем:

1) Разбиваем исходную строку на токены (в вашем случае они идентичны лексемам), например для выражения `3 + 4 * (5 + 2)` это будет:

```
 String[] tokens={"3","+", "4", "*","(","5", "+", "2", ")"};
```

2) Далее согласно правилам грамматики условного языка, проводим парсинг массива токенов результатом которой будет являться дерево инструкций:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3) Теперь когда у нас есть дерево инструкций начинаем обход дерева (обычно рекурсивно) - фактически проводим вычисление:

- Берем знак `+` на вершине дерева
- Находим *детей* (цифра `3` и знак `*`)
- Поскольку у знака `*` есть еще *дети* - то уходим в рекурсию
- ну и т.д.
- после возврата из рекурсии вместо знака `*` у нас будет значение (в данном случае) - `28` - подставляем суммируем и получим `28+3=31`

Можно это конечно и самому запрогать, но кошерным считается вариант, когда вы берете некую либу в которой согласно правилам этой либы вы описываете грамматику и либа соберет вам исходники которые парсят данную грамматику - обычно это задача для курсовой студентов по специальности Software Engineering или что-то в этом роде.

Классикой является [ANTLR](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/4.7.1/doc/getting-started.md)

Comment: Значит, это можно реализовать только с помощью рекурсии ? даже без использования массивов ?

Comment: Любая задача рекурсии сводится к циклу с массивами (по-моему есть такая теорема даже)

Answer (score 4):

Вот библиотека 
    https://github.com/mariuszgromada/MathParser.org-mXparser

Добавляется в проект

```
dependencies {
      /*oter compiles*/
implementation group: 'org.mariuszgromada.math', name: 'MathParser.org-mXparser', version: '4.0.0'
             }
```

Выполняем так

```
 String s = "(3+5)*2";
 Expression e = new Expression();
 e.setExpressionString(s);
 double res = e.calculate();
```

Там еще много функций, поковыряйся - это интересно.

Answer (score 1):

Когда-то я реализовавывал такую штуку, при чем у меня можно было умножать и делать double значения. КОгда я писал этот код, я был очень юн, поэтому не судите строго) Но взять его за идею можно:
https://github.com/georrge1994/1.calculation

Comment: вообще, есть польский метод счета. Вы можете преобразовать выражение в польский вариант и затем считать. Такая реализация намного проще

Answer (score -1):

Строковый калькулятьр, если интересно:
https://gigaom.info/index.php/programmy/strokovyj-kalkulyator
Математический парсер "TFunction" для "Delphi": https://gigaom.info/index.php/iskhodnyj-kod/tfunction-for-delphi
Сергей