# Как обработать нажатие на кнопку на android?

Tags: android, button

Решил сделать калькулятор на андроиде. Но не могу сделать так, чтобы когда я нажал на кнопку, то текст(например нажал на 4 и в editText тоже было 4) отображался? Или я что-то не понимаю? Как мне связать button с editText? Или вообще я не то использую?

Comment: Для этого, изначальное, надо почитать о событиях. Как привязать эти события к кнопке. Потом вам надо изучить, как работать с текстовыми полями, и как в них записывать текст.

Comment: Для `Button` нужно использовать `setOnClickListener` в который добавить `new View.OnClickListener()` в котором собственно реализовать метод `onClick` внутри которого будет производиться вставка в `EditText` с помощью метода `setText`.

Comment: Andorid Studio? Java или Korlin?

Comment: да. на android studio java

Comment: Я вас направил, что вам еще нужно, чтобы за вас написали код?

Comment: нет. я этого не прошу. У меня вот еще возникает проблема. Когда я нажимаю на кнопку, то в editText отображается это число. Но когда я нажимаю на другую кнопку, то новое значение заменяется на старое. Как это исправить?

Comment: Берите то, что есть и пристыковывайте к нему новое значение. Для этого есть методы `getText` и `toString`. Это может выглядеть так: `editText.getText().toString()+newString`.

Comment: В поле ввода EditText не будет выполняться никаких математических вычислений, это поле для строк. То есть вам нужно самому где то хранить посимвольный ввод, соединять 
 с новым воодом, преобразовывать его из строк в числа для вычислений и выводить конечный результат. Так же стоит узнать о обратной польской записи, которую обычно используют при программировании калькуляторов и о классе `KeyboardView` (создание кастомной клавиатуры)

Comment: У вас еще возникнит много разных вопросов, когда вы захотите сделать математические операции. по этому, вам лучше оформлять вопросы правильно: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Строковый калькулятор. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/850439/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80/850470#850470

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализуйте где-либо View.OnClickListener, например прям в активити

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity, View.OnClickListener
```

Студия сообщит, что не хватает методов, жмем alt+enter на этой строке, добавляем метод onClick(v: View)
передайте его кнопкам через setOnClickListener: `findViewById(R.id.button_4).setOnClickListener(this)`

Теперь этот метод будет вызван с нажатой кнопкой в параметре. Соответственно, в нем нужно определить какая кнопка нажата, и получить текст из textView(вам не нужен EditText, он нужен если вы вводите что-то через системную клавиатуру), и прибавить к нему нужную цифру, которую можно получить из текста кнопки.

```
textView.setText(textView.getText() + v.getText())
```

Но это очень примитивный вариант, необходимо правильно обрабатывать вводимые значения, иначе можно получит число с двумя запятыми или еще чего поинтереснее. Я бы рекомендовал сначала попрактиковаться на упражнениях для начинающих, [коих](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/16-urok-9-obrabotchiki-sobytij-na-primere-button.html) в [интернете](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/button.php) не [мало](https://android-school.ru/%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-5-textview-button-%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8/). В том числе и по созданию [калькулятора](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/54-urok-19-pishem-prostoj-kalkuljator.html)

Comment: Спасибо большое!