# Как сделать из строки численное выражение?

Tags: java, android, строки, double

Пишу калькулятор, в который можно вбивать математические выражения любой длины, после чего пользователь нажимает клавишу "=" и калькулятор выполняет вычисления.
Проблема в том, что изначально введённые пользователем данные имеют строковый тип (как на рисунке ниже), как мне преобразовать данную строку в математическое выражение типа double?

[image]

Comment: математическое выражение типа double, это вы что имели в виду?

Comment: @Эникейщик, а куда прописывать text.toDouble()? До меня, пока что не доходит

Comment: @tim bars, есть строка 987+696*9, нужно сделать так, чтобы из этой строки получился результат решения этого примера (в данном случае 7251) как в калькуляторе

Comment: Вот один из вариантов https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/850439/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80/850470#850470

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В простейшем случае все выглядит примерно так...
Для того, чтобы соблюдать порядок действий этот метод не подходит.
Полагаю, что в таком случае реализуется обратная польская запись (но это уже совершенно другая тема для обсуждения).

```
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;
import javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws OperationNotSupportedException {

        String s = "987+696*9";

        Calc calc = new Calc();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (char ch : s.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isDigit(ch) || ch=='.')sb.append(ch);
            else{
                calc.apply(Double.valueOf(sb.toString()));
                calc.apply(MathOperation.getBySymbol(ch));                
                sb = new StringBuilder();
            }
        }
        calc.apply(Double.valueOf(sb.toString()));

        System.out.println(calc.getResult());

    }

}

class Calc{

    private Double result;
    private MathOperation mathOperation;

    public void apply (double digit){
        if (result==null) result = digit;
        else result = mathOperation.applyOperation(result, digit);
    }

    public void apply (MathOperation mathOperation){
        this.mathOperation = mathOperation;
    }

    public double getResult(){
        return result;
    }

}

enum MathOperation{

    MULTIPL('*', (x,y)->x*y), 
    DIVIDION('/', (x,y)->x/y),
    SUBSTRACT('-', (x,y)->x-y),
    ADD('+', (x,y)->x+y);

    private final char symbol;
    private final BinaryOperator<Double> operation;

    private MathOperation(char symbol, BinaryOperator<Double> operation){
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.operation = operation;
    }

    public double applyOperation (double numb1, double numb2){
        return this.operation.apply(numb1, numb2);
    }

    public static MathOperation getBySymbol(final char symbol) throws OperationNotSupportedException {
        for (MathOperation mathOperation : MathOperation.values()) {
            if (mathOperation.symbol==symbol) return mathOperation;
        }
        throw new OperationNotSupportedException("Math.operation " + symbol + " not exist!");
    }

}
```