# Пытаюсь разработать калькулятор, но не знаю, как конвертировать String символ в тернарный оператор

Tags: java, калькулятор

```
public static String operation2(String a, String oper, String b){
        String result = "";
        double res = 0;
        double res2 = 0;
        double res3 = 0;

        char op = '+';
        result = a + oper + b;

        res = Double.parseDouble(a);
        res2 = Double.parseDouble(b);

        res3 = Double.parseDouble(result);

        return Double.toString(res3);
    }
```

Comment: что такое [тернарный оператор](https://yandex.ru/turbo?text=https%3A%2F%2Fru.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F%25D0%25A2%25D0%25B5%25D1%2580%25D0%25BD%25D0%25B0%25D1%2580%25D0%25BD%25D0%25B0%25D1%258F_%25D1%2583%25D1%2581%25D0%25BB%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B2%25D0%25BD%25D0%25B0%25D1%258F_%25D0%25BE%25D0%25BF%25D0%25B5%25D1%2580%25D0%25B0%25D1%2586%25D0%25B8%25D1%258F)

Comment: как, снова калькулятор? эту задачу мы уже решали... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1040990/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5/1041020#1041020

Answer (score 1):

Выражение можно вычислить через ScriptEngine

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
Object result = engine.eval("4*5");
```

Answer (score 0):

Такую реализацию(какую ты предлагаешь) написать, я думаю, нереально, а если и можно, то это будет что-то очень нехорошее. Без условных операторов, switch:case или без foreach не получится.

```java
        int a = 8; // переменная 1
        int b = 6; // переменная 2
        String[] operators = {"+", "-", "*", "/", "%"}; // массив из твоих символов
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
        for (String operator : operators){ // foreach
            Object result = engine.eval(a + operator + b); // выполнение и передача
            System.out.println(result); // вывод
        }//Правда тут он выведет тебе результаты всех операций, поэтому сделай под себя!
```

Answer (score -1):

Можете использовать switch case:

```
switch(operation) {
    case "+":
        result = firstNum + secondNum;
        break;
    case "-":
        result = firstNum - secondNum;
        break;
    case "*":
        result = firstNum * secondNum;
        break;
    case "/":
        result = firstNum / secondNum;
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, дополните существующий текст конкретикой. Пока это скорее комментарий, чем полноценный ответ.